# How do you interpret "we can talk tea"?

Tags: verbs, objects, transitive-verbs, intransitive-verbs

On a package of tea I found a sentence as follows:

> If you have any questions, feedback or are not satisfied with this product, please contact us at our details below and we can **talk tea**.

This makes me confused since, as far as I know, *talk* is basically an intransitive verb and so it isn't followed directly by an object. If an object follows the verb, it should be followed by a preposition like over or through, as in *we talked our problems over*; but there is no such preposition in my example above.

*Oxford Dictionary of English* also provides an usage of the verb with no object: used to emphasise the seriousness, importance, or extent of the thing one is discussing. Considering the context of my example that is related to a product to be discussed, this explanation seems to be the one, though the dictionary only lists up examples where the progressive form is used, like *We're talking big money.*

Comment: I can talk sense. I can talk nonsense. I can talk rubbish. I can talk a load of rubbish. I can talk the hind legs off a donkey, if I am in the mood. And I can definitely talk tea.

Answer (score 2):

The appropriate definition here, according to the Oxford English Dictionary (OED), is:

> To discourse about, speak of, discuss. Now colloq[uial].

I have no clue why it's not in your dictionary, as it's by no means a new use of the word. In my experience, it's also pretty common. There are several idiomatic expressions that use *talk* this way:

- [talk shop](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/talk_shop)
- [talk trash](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/talk_trash)
- [talk nonsense](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/talk-nonsense)

Answer (score 1):

“We can talk tea” basically means they can talk **about** tea with anyone who wants to. The different and more formal way of using it would be to place an “about” between talk and tea. Dictionary.com gives a definition for this kind of talk, and it is “to discuss.” In this sentence, talk and discuss are synonymous.

Answer (score 0):

The [*implied*](https://books.google.com/books?id=zcBDAAAAcAAJ&pg=PA53&lpg=PA53&dq=implied%20preposition&source=bl&ots=FZg-FRMDUb&sig=LLcLRSPilWK45k9oMwmusp60xhU&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiSz82Sqe3ZAhVX7mMKHZKuDSE4ChDoAQgzMAM#v=onepage&q=implied%20preposition&f=false) preposition is **about**, as in:

- Can we talk **about** tea?
- We can talk **about** tea.

> Now it is plain that such verbs, and they form a large proportion of our verbs, are *not transitive*, and upon their introduction into this language must be followed by prepositions either expressed or *implied*, as this is the way we compensate for terminations of cases. But the preposition does not appear in Eng.; the conclusion cannot be resisted; it must be suppressed.
>
> I might mention that the Hebrews say, to shake *with* the head, for shake the head; to open with the mouth, for open the mouth.
>
> Further: prepositions have no power to govern; in Hebrew, they are nouns in derivation; so are they mostly in our language; they cannot govern. The object must have been the subject of an **implied preposition**; its office is now only that of an *adjective*.

*Rough Notes on the Errors of Grammar, and the Nature of Language*, by J. Wilson, c.1858

Answer (score 0):

A humorous take-off on "talk turkey"--speak frankly.

talk turkey
phrase of turkey

1.
   North American informal
   discuss something frankly and straightforwardly.

https://www.google.com/search?q=%22talk+turkey%22&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&client=firefox-b-1

Comment: You should cite your source.

Comment: Done.  See also "talk turkey" on this website.